# Fixing Exporting to Excel with MultiIndexing

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

So here's my problem so far. My Pandas version is 0.15.2 and I'm working on Python 2.7. I'm trying to export a dataframe with MultiIndexed columns to excel without the vertical index. This fully recapitulates my issue:

```
# imports
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
# setting columns
>>> level_one = ['a']*3 + ['b']*3 + ['c']*3
>>> level_two = ['1', '2', '3']*3
>>> columns = [np.array(level_one), np.array(level_two)]
# making the dataframe
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=columns)
>>> series = pd.Series({k:k**2 for k in range(10)})
>>> df[first_col] = series
>>> first_col = df.columns.tolist()[0]
>>> df
     a              b              c          
     1    2    3    1    2    3    1    2    3
 0   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 1   1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 3   9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 4  16  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 5  25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 6  36  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 7  49  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 8  64  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 9  81  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

So, everything works fine so far. Now, when I export to csv, both methods work in terms of data integrity (there is no data shifting relative to the header, although it does repeat each element in level_one).

```
 >>> import os
 >>> path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'test.csv')
 >>> df.to_csv(path)
 >>> df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

However, for the ExcelWriter, it does the following:

```
 >>> import os
 >>> path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'test.xlsx')
 >>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
 >>> df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet 1')
 >>> df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet 2', index=False)
 >>> writer.save()
```

[With Index](http://pastebin.com/ZtMy8xKt)

[Index False](http://pastebin.com/5iNviNyW)

As you can see, it eliminate the index but not in the column header, leading to a data shift. Is there a fix, or a workaround? In my actual data sets, the actual "index" has repetitive elements and spacers, so it's unsuitable to work as an index.

Comment: Also going to add: this happens also if I have a multiIndexed index and columns, except, the offset is still only one. In short, the output is the exact same, despite the fact that the index now takes up "n" columns rather than 1.

Comment: I've also tried this with all 3 engines now (XlsxWriter, OpenPyXl, and Xlwt), and the error is the exact same for all 3. Should I submit a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find anything in the documentation to address this, but I came up with a temporary fix.

```
import itertools

def pseudo_header(df):
    '''Create a pseudo-header for the dataframe due to indexing
    issues.
    '''

    # grab grouped columns
    columns = df.columns
    grouped = itertools.groupby(columns, key=lambda x: x[0])
    grouped = [tuple(v) for k, v in grouped]
    # grab col/index counters
    index = DF.get_last_index(df)
    counter = 0
    # set rows
    df.loc[index] = pd.Series(index=columns)
    df.loc[index+1] = pd.Series(index=columns)
    for group in grouped:
        for idx, values in enumerate(group):
            # grab indexing
            column = columns[counter]
            if idx == 0:
            df.loc[index, column] = values[0]
            df.loc[index+1, column] = values[1]
            counter += 1
```

Then, I export with the index and the header off. It works, there's no header formatting, but it's not a bad fix.

Currently, only works for a 2-level header, and I could generalize, but for my needs it's not necessary right now.